# Two threads working on the same list

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking

I'm working on a P2P application in C#.
It's a file transfer with a file splitting, and text chat.

On a client there are 2 threads, 1 for listening, 1 for sending.
When i send a file, it's first split into let's say 10 pieces, these 10 pieces are added to a send queue in the client, it then starts sending file chunk 1.
But now i want to send a message through the same pipe.
My idea is then to insert that message into the send list before file chunk 2.
What kind of threading do i need for 2 threads to work on the same list?
I have accounted for the objects being received this way.

My initial idea for the send function was something along these lines:

```
public void Send()
{
    while (IsConnected())
    {
        if (unSentObjects.Count > 1)
        {
            Task sendTask = new Task(() => SendObj(unSentObjects[0]));
            sendTask.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Synchronization Object` such as a mutex to prevent race conditions or simultaneous write/read to same file. Basically only 1 thread will be able to access the object.

If the data is global to the threads and they are all once process, you can use the synchronization object simply to signal when to use global shared data and when to not use it. Other than that using the shared global data is exactly the same, you are just trafficking the use of it.

Comment: Like a flag which is a `bool` called `ItemInUse`. This object requires waiting to access it and utilizes Synchronization objects. The actual data for your application doesn't. Simply if `ItemInUse` is false, set it to true, then do what ever you want with the data, then when finished set it to false again.

Comment: The queue is local to the sender thread, then thread 2 adds new objects to sending queue. But i can't do that because as you say it's a simultaneous read/write, but aren't there a way to add a new object after it's done sending chunk 1?